# How to display dynamodb table names of respective user

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

php code for dynamodb. I am facing problem at displaying the table names using ListTables() api call. I done like this.

STEP1: In AWS IAM, I created two users named 'user1' and 'user2' in IAM. The IAM console created the credentials (access key and secret key) for both users 'user1' and 'user2'. In dynamodb, i created two tables Books and Users.

STEP2: For user1, I given access to only table named 'Books'. I written the policy document as below (Under Resource, i mentioned the ARN of the table name 'Books'. )

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [                 
             "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
             "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
             "dynamodb:GetItem",
             "dynamodb:ListTables",
             "dynamodb:Query",
             "dynamodb:Scan",
             "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity",
             "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings",
             "dynamodb:ListTagsOfResource"                 
         ],
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:468737190093:table/Books",

     }]
}
```

STEP3: For user2, I given access to only table named 'Users'. I written the policy document as below (Under Resource, i mentioned table name 'Users'. )

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:ListTables",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity",
            "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings",
            "dynamodb:ListTagsOfResource"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:468737190093:table/Users"
        ]

    }]
}
```

Now my goal is to display the table names of respective user. If i login with user1 (with user1's credentials accesskey and secret key), I need to display only table name 'Books'. or if i login with user2(with user2's credentials:  accesskey and secret key), i need to display only "Users'.
I tried with ListTables() api call. But not achieved what i want.

```
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => $userAccessKey,
        'secret' => $userSecretKey
    ),
    'http' => [
        'verify' => 'D:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\cacert.pem'
    ]
]);
$dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
$result = $dynamodb->listTables();



 echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($result['TableNames'] as $tableName) {   
        echo '<li><a href="table.php?var1='.$tableName.'">'.$tableName.'</a>              
    </li>';
 }
echo '</ul>';
```

I am getting below exception:
AccessDeniedException","Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::468737190093:user/user1 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:ListTables on resource: *

Note: If i changed the Resource field to "*" in the policy document, then it is displaying all the table names successfully (Books, Users). But i need to display only tables names of respective user (user1 --> Display only 'Books', user2--> Display only 'Users').

If not ListTables(), is there any other api calls or any other ways available in dynamodb to list the table names?
Can someone give me solutions..:)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution. I used the error code to solve this. (i put try catch block to catch the error).

**step1:**  Change the policy document such that user has two kind of permissions.
1. Permission to access some dynamodb api calls like BatchGetItem(), DescribeTable()...etc  with below resource (resouce name as arn of table 'Books')
"Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:468737190093:table/Books",

2. Permission to access the api call ListTables with below resource (resource name for all tables).
   "Resource": "*"

   {

   "Version": "2012-10-17",

   ```
   "Statement": [
    {
       "Action": [                 
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:ListTables",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity",
            "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings",
            "dynamodb:ListTagsOfResource"                 
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Rsource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:468737190093:table/Books"
    },
    {
           "Action": [
               "dynamodb:ListTables"
           ],
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": "*"
     }
   ```

   ]
   }

Change the permission to user2 also (in the same way as user1).

**step2:** get all tables by using listtables() api.
$result = $dynamodb->listTables();

**step3:** define an array userTables. Do scan() on each table. If we got an exception with error code: 'AccessDeniedException', then don't add that table name to the array. Add the rest of the table names to the array.

```
$userTables = array();
foreach ($result['TableNames'] as $tableName) {         


        try
        {
                $result1 = $dynamodb->scan([
                    'TableName' => $tableName
                ]);
        }
        catch(\Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException $e)
        {               
                $errCode = $e->getAwsErrorCode();
                //echo "<br>***Error Code: $errCode";
                if($errCode == "AccessDeniedException")             
                {
                        //echo "<br>No Permission to access the table named: <b>$tableName</b><br>";
                        continue; // Don't add this table, because the user don't have permission to this table.

                }
        }

        // Add this table name to array userTables.
        array_push($userTables, $tableName);

}
```

step4: display the table names using the array userTables.